# dependencies from pom.xml not being resolved

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to create a maven project in intellij, to create a parser in antlr. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mua</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-parser-java-antlr</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Json parser Java ANTLR</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>Trying to create a parser using ANTLR in Java, as facing problems with LLVM</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I click on import changes, it loads for just 1-2 seconds then done. But if I try to import `MapUtils` from `org.apache.commons.collections4.MapUtils` it says it can't resolve `common`, although I added in `<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>` dependency.

I'm new in maven project creation and management.

So, what is the problem here and how can I resolve this problem ?

*I studied some `pom.xml` and found a `parent` attribute. No idea how to configure that.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Eclipse editor shows:

```
Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar is missing.
Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar is missing.
Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:jar is missing.
```

None of the dependencies work, because it doesn't know which version of them you want.

Specifying dependencies without a version is something you do when you have a *parent* pom. You don't, so versions are mandatory.

Comment: I tried version `<version>LATEST</version>` again it doesn't work..

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Don't try generic versions like `LATEST` or `RELEASE`, but use version numbers.

Comment: Yeah, some random version even worked, how funny that latest didn't... Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Why did you believe that `LATEST` is a supported value? It is certainly not mentioned anywhere in the [**POM Reference**](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) documentation!

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a specific version of antlr to your pom.xml. And if you are using the antlr plugin as well, make sure the version of antlr run-time you are using is the same as the built-in version of the plugin.